# Guess about the integral curve is not closed

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

For given smooth vector field $X$ on Riemannian manifold,solution of $\dot c=X(c)$ is the flow line or integral curve.

Then the point $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow\infty} c_p(t)$ need not be contained in the flow line.But I think if the manifold is compact it will be contained in the flow line.Is it right ?

Comment: If $X$ is the gradient of the smooth function $x$ on the unit circle....

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang  Sorry,I just a beginner, I can't under understand you . If $X$ is gradient of $x$, then I have $X=\nabla x$. Then $\dot c=\nabla x(c)$ , then ?

Comment: @lanse7pty I think that Andrew D. Hwang is suggesting that your claim is false.  Namely, if $x$ is a smooth function on the unit circle, then ( by compactness) $x$ must obtain both a maximum and minimum value.  At points of extrema, the differential 1-form $dx$ must be zero.  The corresponding vector field $X$ that is metrically dual to $dx$ must then also be zero at the points in question.  According to existence and uniqueness theorems of differential equations, it is impossible for the flow lines of $X$ to be periodic as your flow lines will be trapped between the singular points of $X$.

Comment: @lanse7pty  It should also be noted that you can see that your claim is false without appealing to gradient fields (in which case you don't need the Riemannian structure) or vector fields with singularities (which every gradient field will have on a compact Riemannian manifold).  The classical example of this is the torus $S^{1} \times S^{1}$ identified with the quotient $\mathbb{R}^{2}/\mathbb{Z}^{2}$.  Take a constant vector field $X$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.  If the flow lines of $X$ have rational slope, then the flow lines on the torus are periodic . . . (cont.)

Comment: . . . but if the flow lines have irrational slope then they are all dense on the torus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector field $X(\theta) = \sin \theta$ on the real line has zeros at integer multiples of $\pi$, and no flow line reaches a zero in finite time. Because $X$ is invariant under translation by $2\pi$, $X$ descends to the (compact) quotient, a circle. The character of the flow on the quotient is locally identical to the flow "upstairs". Particularly, no flow line reaches its limit in finite time.